# Match some text sheet 1 a with sheet 2 a if match paste sheet 1 b to sheet 2 b

Tags: excel, copy, match, vba

I have a sheet1 that has names in column A and I have names in sheet 2 column A.  The names are mostly the same, besides a comma or period on sheet 2 and not on sheet 1.  I need to match some of the text and take sheet 1 column B and paste to sheet 2 column B.

example:

Sheet 1

```
A                        B
Doug, Inc.             $12.03
For it all, LLC        $4452.03
Go for it, Inc.        $235.60

Sheet 2
A                        B
Doug, Inc - Joe          
For it all - Mike
Go for it Inc - Tom
```

I have code that will match and paste only if the names match exact, before the dash "-".
I need help getting it to match just some of the text, not caring about the comma's or periods.

```
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set ws1 = Sheets(1)
    Set ws2 = Sheets(2)
    Set rng1 = ws2.Range(ws2.[a1], ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
 With rng1.Offset(0, 1)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]<>"""",IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(LEFT(RC[-1],FIND("" - "",RC[-1])-1),'" & ws1.Name & "'!C[-1],0))),INDEX('" & ws1.Name & "'!C,MATCH(LEFT(RC[-1],FIND("" - "",RC[-1])-1),'" & ws1.Name & "'!C[-1],0)),""""),"""")"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I have refactored your formula

1. It will simplify your code if you use a Named Range for your sheet 1 data.  Here I've used the name `Data`
2. I've used `VLookup` rather than `Index(Match(` to further shorthen the formula
3. The double `Substitute`'s replace `,` and `.` in the lookup range
4. The formula must be an `Array formula` for the `Substitues` to work.
5. Because of the `Substitute` the returned value is a string.  I've wraqpped the function in a `Value` to convert back to a number, Remove this if not required.
6. The lookup value is prepared before the call to VLookup, stripping off the `- ...` if present

'

```
.FormulaArray = "=VALUE(VLOOKUP(" & _
  "LEFT(RC[-1],IFERROR(FIND("" - "",RC[-1])-1,LEN(RC[-1])))," & _
  "SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Data,"","",""""),""."",""""),2,0))"
```

There is one aspect of your sample data that I am unsure about
`For it all - Mike` will become `For it all`.
 - This *won't* match `For it all, LLC` (which becomes `For it all LLC`)

`Go for it Inc - Tom` will become `Go for it Inc`.
 - This *will* match `Go for it, Inc.` (which becomes `Go for it Inc`)

`Doug, Inc - Joe` will become `Doug, Inc`.
 - This *won't* match `Doug, Inc.` (which becomes Doug Inc`)

If you want to ignore `,` and `.` in *both* sheets, use

```
.FormulaArray = "=VALUE(VLOOKUP(" & _
  "SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(RC[-1],IFERROR(FIND("" - "",RC[-1])-1,LEN(RC[-1]))),"","",""""),""."","""")," & _
  "SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Data,"","",""""),""."",""""),2,0))"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve.  I do not understand your code which just seems to clear column B of sheet 2.  I do not understand why you are using a macro to set formula.

The code below does what I think you are trying to do.  If not, I hope my code gives you enough ideas so you can create the code you seek.

I am guessing you are not that familiar with Excel Basic.  Sorry if the following insults your knowledge.  I assume you would rather be insulted than confused.

```
Sub Test2()

  ' This is revised coding.  I had not read the question carefully enough
  ' so my original code did not do what was required.

  Dim Pos2 As Integer           ' The 1s and 2s in variable names
  Dim RowCrnt As Integer        ' identify the variable as being for Sheet1
  Dim RowMax As Integer         ' or Sheet2.  The same row variables are
  Dim S1ColAB() As Variant      ' used for both sheets.
  Dim S2ColAB() As Variant
  Dim Value1 As String
  Dim Value2 As String

  With Sheets("Sheet2")
    ' I generally use Find instead of End(xlUp) for reasons I no longer
    ' remember. This searches column A (Columns("A")) for anything ("*")
    ' starting from cell A1 (Range("A1")) and moving backwards
    ' (xlPrevious) until it finds a value.
    RowMax = .Columns("A").Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , _
                                                xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

    ' Range(Cells(A,B),Cells(C,D)) defines a rectangle of cells with Row=A,
    ' Col=B as top left and Row=C, Col=D as bottom right.
    ' The following statement loads the contents of a block of cells to a
    ' variant array.  Another question has led to a discussion about the value
    ' of using variant arrays in this way.  I have found that moving values
    ' from one sheet to another can be very slow so I believe it is useful in
    ' this situation.
    S2ColAB = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(RowMax, 2)).Value

    ' Warning about moving values from a cell into a string or variant variable
    ' and then from the variable into another cell.
    ' =========================================================================
    ' When moving the value from the variable to the cell, Excel will
    ' misinterpret the value if it can.
    '
    ' For example, if the value is 13/1/11 (13 January 2011 here in England)
    ' this value will be correctly transferred into the new cell.  But if the
    ' value is 4/1/11 (4 January 2011), Excel will recognise this as a valid
    ' American date and set the new cell to 1 April 2011.  The damage that bug
    ' caused by corrupting a third my dates!  I had tested my code towards the
    ' end of a month and it worked perfectly until the next month.
    '
    ' In this example, string $12.03 becomes currency 12.03 and displays
    ' here as £12.03.

  End With

  With Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' Load the matching cells from sheet 1
    S1ColAB = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(RowMax, 2)).Value
  End With

  With Sheets("Sheet2")
    For RowCrnt = 1 To RowMax
      ' I move the Column A values for matching row from the arrays to string
      ' variables so I can amend their values without losing the original
      ' values.  This was essential with my original code and I have not
      ' changed it since I think it makes the code easier to understand and
      ' probably marginally faster.
      Value1 = S1ColAB(RowCrnt, 1)
      Value2 = S2ColAB(RowCrnt, 1)
      ' The following code removes anything following a hyphen from Value 2.
      ' It then removes all commas and dots from both Value1 and Value2.  If
      ' the final values are the same, it moves the Column B of Sheet1 to
      ' Sheet2.
      Pos2 = InStr(1, Value2, "-")
      If Pos2 <> 0 Then
        ' Pos2 is not zero so extract the portion of Value2 up to the "-"
        ' and then trim trailing spaces.
        Value2 = RTrim(Mid(Value2, 1, Pos2 - 1))
      End If
      ' Replace all commas with nothing.
      Value1 = Replace(Value1, ",", "")
      ' Replace all dots with nothing.
      Value1 = Replace(Value1, ".", "")
      ' Merge the two replaces into a single statement.
      Value2 = Replace(Replace(Value2, ",", ""), ".", "")
      If Value1 = Value2 Then
        ' If the modified values are equal, copy the Column 2 (B) from
        ' Sheet1 to Sheet2.
        .Cells(RowCrnt, 2).Value = S1ColAB(RowCrnt, 2)
      End If
    Next

  End With

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.  Come back if I have not explained myself adequately.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I gave your code a try and nothing happen.  I am trying to just match column A on each sheet and then if A match, then match column B on each sheet.  The names are almost the same, but have a comma or period added or not there.  So my logic is if sheet1 A1 = sheet2 A1 then Sheet2 B1 will = Sheet1 B1

Comment: Sorry @user1013478 I did not notice your response until now.  When I tested my code with sheets like yours it did what I planned but this was not what you wanted and you may not have noticed the effect.  I did not appreciate you wanted Column B changed.  My code takes the two Column A values, removes anything following a hyphen and any commas and dots.  If the resultant values are the same, it sets the Sheet 2 Column A to the unchanged Sheet 1 Column A.  It does not nothing to either Column B.  I will look for my test workbook, amend my code to update Column B and amend my original posting.